# How to get datetime records in "dd/mm/yyyy h:m:s" format FROM SQL server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to get records from sql server 2005 in datetime format like this  "dd/mm/yyyy h:m:s"

My database date is default datetime format

```
AttLogId int
...
DownloadLog datetime
```

I am trying to retrieve the datetime like this:

```
SELECT AttLogId ,convert(varchar,DownloadLogDate,103) FROM  AttLog
ORDER BY DownloadLogDate
```

but I only get the date and not the time.

Comment: Take a look at [this blogpost](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) from Anubhav Goyal. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you don't try to get the values in a particular string format. Fetch them as `DateTime` values and then format them in the .NET code using `DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s")`.

It's almost *always* worth keeping data in its "natural" data type (date/time here) for as long as possible, only converting to text when you really need to. So your SQL should just be:

```
SELECT AttLogId, DownloadLogDate FROM  AttLog
ORDER BY DownloadLogDate
```

How you then retrieve the data will depend on how you're talking to SQL (e.g. LINQ to SQL, using `SqlDbReader` etc). But you should be able to get it as a `DateTime` and then format it locally. This will make it easier to test, easier to debug, give you more control over cultural aspects (date separators, possibly specifying a standard specifier instead of a custom one, etc).

Comment: Help me for I can not ASK Question so Help me , Erro Like This = Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: @JigJet12: I suggest you follow the advice on that page then.

Comment: @Jig12: So did this not work for you? It really would be *much* cleaner than converting it in the database. You should avoid performing string conversions any earlier than you really need to.

Comment: :: OK Thank you, You give me proper suggestion  :)

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are using 103 , so it will give only date .
if you want more format check this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to need, u can try this

```
SELECT AttLogId , convert(varchar(10),DownloadLogDate,103) +'  '+ convert(varchar(8),DownloadLogDate,108) FROM  AttLog ORDER BY DownloadLogDate
```

Note : firstone is for date and second one is for time in H:M:S

hope this help u..